# variable which needs a fix

Tags: php, html

I was trying to echo a variable before it was even defined so literally i'm getting this error "UNDEFINED VARIABLE: tpp"

```
<tr>
    <td colspan='6'>
        <h4><small>Trusted Players List <?php echo $tpp ?> Total)</small></h4>
    </td>
</tr>
```

When i set that line down along with echo "" , it works. But i want it on the place where i set it [Top]

Here is the code which i need help with

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td colspan='6'>
                <h4><small>Trusted Players List <?php echo $tpp ?> Total)</small></h4>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <td>Number</td>
        <td>Username</td>
        <td>Last Login</td>
    </thead>
    <?php
        $query = $koneksi->prepare("SELECT `user`, `TP`, `LastOnlineDate` FROM `playerdata` WHERE `banned`=0 AND `TP`=1");
        $query->execute();
            if($query->rowCount() == 0)
        {
            echo "<tr><td colspan='6'><small>No rows found</small></td></tr>";
        }
        $tpp = 0;
        while($data = $query->fetch())
        {
            $tpp++;
            echo "<tr><td>".$tpp."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$data['user']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$data['LastOnlineDate']."</td></tr>";
        }
        ?>
</table>
```

Any help will be so appreciated

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$tpp` is undefined because its being called before its been created, Try this out instead.

```
 <?php

  $tpp = 0;
  $content = "";

  $query = $koneksi->prepare("SELECT `user`, `TP`, `LastOnlineDate` FROM `playerdata` WHERE `banned`=0 AND `TP`=1");
  $query->execute();
  while($data = $query->fetch())
  {
     $tpp++;
     $content .= "<tr><td>".$tpp."</td>";
     $content .= "<td>".$data['user']."</td>";
     $content .= "<td>".$data['LastOnlineDate']."</td></tr>";
  }

?>

<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td colspan='6'><h4><small>Trusted Players List <?php echo $tpp ?> Total)</small></h4></td>
    </tr>
    <td>Number</td>
    <td>Username</td>
    <td>Last Login</td>
  </thead>

 <?php

        if($query->rowCount() == 0)
        {
            echo "<tr><td colspan='6'><small>No rows found</small></td></tr>";
        }


        echo $content;

        ?>
</table>
```

I've decided to run the loop at the top, placing all the data within `$content` and then `echo $content` where you wish to display the content. This allows you to still have your counter run and be displayed at the top of the table.

Comment: You get my vote, but I would've separated the data, adding it to an array in the while loop and then printing it as you please in the table ;-)

Comment: Yeah i thought of that, but figured for a simpler solution just to create it all within `$content`. Thanks @Darren

Comment: Both perfectly reasonable options at doing it!